# Is GMT same as UTC?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, timezone

I am running a world targeted website where people from all over the world visit. The database contains time in International Date Line West format. I am taking the user time zone using JavaScript and converting the time in the database to user's time and then showing on the page. I want to ask that is International Date Line West is correct format for world level website? Or setting to UTC or GMT will be better? And what is the difference between UTC and GMT and International Date Line West? Are these three same? Finally what time should I set onto my server that will be converted using offset of timezone of user?

Comment: From my understanding, UTC is GMT but without daylight savings.  However I learned long ago to stay far away from messy datetime issues.

Comment: Short answer yes. Long answer no. GMT never has "daylight savings", then it is called "BST" or another name, so that is not an issue. The main thing is GMT and UTC can vary by up to but never more than 500ms.

Comment: @Servy — In the UK when Daylight Savings kicks in, we move timezones to BST (which is GMT+1).

Comment: Hmm... @Servy, why do we in the UK go to GMT+1 in the summer then?

Comment: so what timezone should I set on server?

Comment: @ShivaPareek — Whatever time zone you want to work in.

Comment: I think UTC is the standard these days.

Comment: @Quentin see the time offset returns the difference from UTC. And there is no UTC in Windows Timezone setup. So I want to ask what it is called now? GMT?

Comment: @JohnWillemse: yes. You should store all your dates as UTC in the DB. Your server's timezone is really irrelevant to this problem. It's the conversion from UTC to the timezone of your clients that should be your concern.

Comment: I think you should have a look at this link > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: Just to add a link to the conversation - http://www.diffen.com/difference/GMT_vs_UTC

Comment: @PaulS. your comment that GMT and UTC can vary by up to 500ms is incorrect.  You are thinking about UTC vs UT1.

Comment: @PaulS. is correct in that GMT and UTC differ by a fraction of a second, but the difference can be up to 900 ms.  UTC is based on UT1, but with an integer number of leap seconds inserted as required to remain approximately equal to GMT. (where GMT is based on solar observation rather than atomic clocks)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you're interested in astronomical observations, for example of satellites such as [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System), or if you want to cite a technical standard ([ITU-R TF.460-6](https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-TF.460/en)), then you might care that we use UTC and that GMT no longer has a precise definition. Otherwise you probably consider GMT to be the same thing as UTC, and also consider [UT and UT1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time) to be the same as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) — which technically they are not.

Also, if you're tracking computer criminals or other distributed activity, then you need to determine whether certain events at various sites may or may not have occurred before certain other events. For that purpose you will want to learn and use [Network Time Protocol (NTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). That will have a much bigger effect on your understanding of time than the little differences between UTC, UT1, and UT.

"[International Date Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line) West" is just a friendly name for a timezone where the time is defined as twelve hours less than UTC (that is, UTC-12).

Comment: How is it a friendly name? I would have expected UTC+12 (eg: Suva)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Is it the same or not?

Comment: Oops, I used pronouns "which" and "they" in an unclear way. I was thinking of all of "GMT" (by a definition such as, mean solar time at Greenwich meridian), UTC, UT1, and "UT" (by any of its other definitions such as UT0). While all of these approximate each other, much of the time their exact values are all different.

Comment: @Jasen Going by the Time Zone rules, International Date Line *East* should be UST+12

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ Suva is West of the IDL but IDLW describes a zone thats that's east of the date line.

Comment: UTC+12 is ambiguous, POSIX and ISO have opposite interpretations.

Comment: @artem-novikov The difference that I proposed was, whether the definitions have a generally recognized authority. Examining further, isn't GMT a "mean time" as in mean solar time? That's timekeeping with respect to the average solar day, the period between noon times, when the Sun crosses of the plane through Earth's poles and some other location for observing from Earth. One second would equal 1/86,400 of it. In contrast, UTC is defined in the international system of units, where, in sun or in rain :-), one second is no more and no less than 9 192 631 770 cycles of a Cesium atomic clock.

Answer (score 32):

UTC is effectively the new name for GMT. It has very minor differences, but none that will impact you in that scenario.

Servy's comment is completely wrong saying GMT includes daylight savings. That's a different timezone called BST that the UK moves to from GMT over summer.

Comment: UTC uses leap seconds to compensate for the irregularity of the earth and suns movements, this means that sometimes a minute in UTC may have 59 or 61 seconds. However, because it is based on zero degrees longitude, which passes through the Greenwich Observatory, it happens to usually match GMT. Note that UTC has no daylight savings time.

Comment: What about International Date Line? Can you tell me what's that?

Comment: That one is easy to find on google :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Date_Line

Comment: Ya I already read that but I am unable to understand that its a time zone or what? Should I set that? Because my server is in that time zone currently.

Comment: Actually, it's not a renaming: GMT is a timezone, and UTC is a time standard. See https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you have to present dates or times to people in different timezones what you should do is save all time information in UTC on your database and convert it to the users timezone on the display layer (when your presenting the information to your user)

However you will find a couple of challenges:
- The timezone you get from javascript may not be trustworthy
- Finding the location of the user through the IP and then getting the timezone is also not trustworthy

A good approach in my opinion is to use a "best guess" to find the default timezone (javascript timezone should suffice) and give the user the ability to actively configure his timezone.

On some google applications their approach is to prompt the user for his timezone before starting, this should be done only when you can guarantee that you don't have to repeat this every time the user visits your site (through user accounts or cookies)

Comment: But in that case we have to set cookie for unregistered and database entry for registered. But as of my experience, some people even don't know what's timezone? ...then what about them..So we want to take care of all these issues

Comment: You missunderstood. All date and time information is saved as UTC in the database. When a user visits your site you convert that date time information into the timezone of the user. The idea is to guarantee he doesnt have to know much about timezones, all dates and times presented to him are in his timezone.

Comment: I don't think so..because my database doesn't save time in UTC. It saves in my local time. that is Indian time.

Comment: You can force your database to save it to UTC by either configuring it to use UTC timezone as default (my.cnf) or sending "SET time_zone='+0:00'" with every connection.

Comment: @ShivaPareek You may be using the wrong data type in your database.  In databases that comply with the SQL standard, such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), a column of data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` will save a moment with respect for the input’s time zone or offset-from-UTC — in most databases this means using the provided zone/offset to adjust the value to UTC before storing. In contrast, the data type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` ignores any zone/offset info provided with an input, and instead stores simply the date and time-of-day.