# Why the result of 'gmtime, strftime' is different compiled with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc and mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc

Tags: c, arm, mips

I use `strftime` to format the time. `%Z` format the time timezone. But the result is *GMT* compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`, *UTC* compiled with `mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc`.

I don't know why.

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
char stat_timestamp[24] = {0};
strftime(stat_timestamp, sizeof stat_timestamp, "%F %T %Z", gmtime(&t));
printf("gmtime: %s\n", stat_timestamp);
```

compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`:

```
gmtime: 2018-12-21 XX:XX:XX GMT
```

compiled with `mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc`:

```
gmtime: 2018-12-21 XX:XX:XX UTC
```

Comment: The two systems use a different name for the timezone.  Is there something more that that you seek?  I recommend using a wider `char stat_timestamp[24]` --> `char stat_timestamp[100]` for this investigation as insufficient buffers result in an indeterminate `stat_timestamp[]`.

Comment: Timezone names come from system configuration, not the C library.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the result of 'gmtime, strftime' is different

- Implementation defined behavior.

C does not require it to be the same across various platforms.

> `%Z` is replaced by the locale’s time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no time zone is determinable. `[tm_isdst]` C11dr §7.26.3.5 3
>
> In the `"C"` locale ... `%Z` implementation-defined. §7.26.3.5 7

Note that [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is akin to [GMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).  See also [Is GMT same as UTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14986043/2410359)

Answer (score 0):

The correct value is actually `GMT`, which is a time *zone.* `UTC` is not a time zone (unless possibly if you're using it as shorthand for `UTC+0`) but is instead a time *standard,* but people often mistakenly use `UTC` as a zone.

There is no real restriction on what implementations return as the time zone since the standard has only this to say:

> `%Z` is replaced by the locale's time zone name or abbreviation, or by no characters if no time zone is determinable.

The local time zone and daylight savings time are some of the items lised under "Unspecified behaviour".